# Facebook Graph. Get all the albums and the photos from a page

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the photos from all the albums of a Facebook page that will be shown on a web page. I'm getting a bit confused with the access token. I don't want the user to have to log in to Facebook to be able to see the photos so I'm not sure how to get the token. Do I have to make an application to connect to for this?

Comment: sure you can: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, albums aren't generally public unless a user has made them public, and even them I'm not sure as to whether the API would let you access them without a user logging into it first. I don't know much about the Facebook API, but if it's anything like the Twitter one you get the access token as a response from the user logging in via the API.

Comment: I'd presumed the fan pages were visible without being logged in but apparently not. Can I get the website to 'log in' and get the photos and display them?